# Can I make a pull request on a gist on GitHub?

Tags: git, github, gist, pull-request

Can I make a pull request on some else's gist on GitHub?

I'm aware of the fork, clone and commit workflow for a gist I own. I'd like to know if I can request to update someone else's gist with my fork.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688185/how-to-merge-a-gist-on-github

Comment: FYI, see ["Feature request: Add support for web-based pull-requests for Gist"](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/1719)

Comment: @MartinMonperrus let's upvote the issue request to get more attention.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

You cannot currently open a pull request on a Gist.

You can comment though on the Gist and ask the author to update the Gist from your fork.

Comment: Unfortunately, since it is a git repository you can already clone it. They just haven't surfaced the pull request aspect.

Comment: Furthermore, pull requests, issues, and other github features on gists would be an anti-pattern. Here is why. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47336590/117471

Comment: It's strange that you can fork a Gist, but cannot submit a pull request.

Answer (score 29):

As @Kevin said, unfortunately GitHub doesn't expose a GUI for pull requests on gists. You can however fork the gist, make your changes in the fork, then share a link to your fork with the original author.

If the original author is keeping a local cloned repository of their gist (see *[How do you manage your gists on github?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2082723/how-do-you-manage-your-gists-on-github)*) then they can do a pull against your fork as a remote using the gist # (e.g. `git://gist.github.com/1131276`).

Answer (score 19):

I have sent a feature request email to `support@github.com` and pointed to this question.

[Ivan Žužak](https://github.com/izuzak) replied with the usual:

> I've added that to our feature request list so that the team can consider it.

confirming it is not possible.

Let's keep upvoting this question until it happens.

I recommend instead creating one regular repo called `gists` and ordering your gists into regular folders.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think it is appropriate to have pull request on gists. The intent of gist.github.com was to improve upon the [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/archive/python) concept commonly used in IRC and forums. They chose to call the service "gist" because [as vocabulary.com describes it...](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/gist)

> When you need a quick summary of the essentials, rather than the whole story or a thorough explanation, you're looking for the ***gist***.

However I will concede that github is missing a very important feature. The ability to [create a full github repo out of a gist and keep metadata about its origins](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40407301/117471).

That would solve most of what people need. At that point, the only form of "request" that someone would need to submit is "hey, won't you make a full repo out of this." And that can be done in the comments. By **NOT** allowing `pull requests`, `issues`, etc. on gists, it allows the author to reply to such a comment with, "nah, it was just a hack I threw together and don't intend to support."

```
StackOverflow won't let you link to pastebin without including a code block. Done.
```

Answer (score 5):

Pulling Gists isn't possible in the same manner as `git pull`, one could provide the changes via Gist in the form of a `.diff`/`.patch`. This can be done locally in your working directory with [diff](http://linux.die.net/man/1/diff) or via GitHub if it's already forked there:

- **Original**: https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/commit/c6f93eeab2
- **diff:** https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/commit/c6f93eeab2.diff
- **patch:** https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker/commit/c6f93eeab2.patch

This way, it's differential and a lot easier to view/apply the changes, especially if it affects multiple files.

Answer (score 0):

I too would very much appreciate the capability to make (or receive) pull requests to/from gists.

Since it's [not possible to make a pull request to a gist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8767309/5783745), I have found that the best **alternative is to simply write the contents of the gist in a standard GitHub repository `README.md` file**.

That will:

- appear visually very similarly to a gist, and
- can be forked just like a gist, but
- changes made to the forks can be pull request-ed back to the original (desired behaviour)

Although it doesn't let you PR to a gist, I hope it helps somewhat.