# How to merge a gist on GitHub?

Tags: git, version-control, github

I have a gist on GitHub that someone forked and made changes to. I like their changes.

Is there a way to merge the changes back into my original gist?

Comment: Gists are plain git repositories. You could clone yours, fetch the fork, merge the fork and push. (Although i'm interested in finding about a less CLI way of doing it)

Comment: My question specifically is about merging changes someone made in a forked version of my gist back into my original gist. Can you propose the commands in an answer?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

A gist operates like any other repository.  So let's say you've cloned something like git://gist.github.com/2322786.git:

```
$ git clone git@gist.github.com:2322786.git
```

(If you just wanted to try this without pushing, you can use `git://gist.github.com/2322786.git`, which will demonstrate the merge principle and works anonymously, but does not allow you to push.)

And now you want to merge in changes from git://gist.github.com/2661995.git.  Add it as an additional remote:

```
$ git remote add changes git://gist.github.com/2661995.git
$ git fetch changes
```

And then merge in the changes like this:

```
$ git merge changes/master
```

And you should be all set.  This should work regardless of whether the new gist was forked from yours at some previous point or is completely unrelated.

Taking Romain's comment into account, you would then issue a `push`:

```
$ git push
```

This would only work if your original clone URL allows writing.

Comment: This does not update the gist as shown on the website - which is what the OP wants to happen.

Comment: Certainly.  This was just to illustrate things in a way that would let someone simply copy and paste my examples.  You jumped the gun on that second comment a a bit.  Take a breather :).

Comment: If you don't include the `push`, you don't answer the question. If you don't answer the question fully, I take my upvote off ;)

Comment: I got this error: fatal: remote error: 
  You can't push to git://github.com/2711857.git
  Use git@github.com:2711857.git  -- I'm going to change my remote definition.

Comment: Yeah, that's what @Romain was talking about.  You can only push to the ssh URL.  See ROmain's first comment...I'm updating my answer to include both URLs, since I really wanted something that would work for someone trying to copy/paste these command, too.

Comment: Thanks - I see now. Thanks @Romain as well. All done and was just what I was looking for.