# show github gist git submodule page link

Tags: git, github, git-submodules, gist

I've added submodules from github before and I like that you can click on the submodule link and it takes you to the submod repo page. However, with gists as submodules it seems like that is not the case.

Is there anything I can do to fix this? Is this a github issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fork Gist to Repo on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21811581/fork-gist-to-repo-on-github)